# Where is the payload of a page struct

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm studying the MM in Linux and I got very confused when I could't find where the raw data is stored. I thought it was stored in some field of a [page struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L41) but I couldn't find there.

Where is the actual data represented by a page stored? And how to get a pointer to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use page_address() to get virtual address of a page.
But the return address might be NULL due to the fact that not all pages have mapped virtual addresses.

```
void *page_address(const struct page *page);
```

You could use kmap to map a highmen page to a virtual address.
Also, remember to use kunmap to unmap this page when you don't need to access it.

```
struct page *page = alloc_pages(GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_HIGHMEM, 0);
if (page) {
    void *addr = kmap(page);
    if (addr) {
        memset(addr, 0, PAGE_SIZE);
        kunmap(addr);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 So, this looks like what I wanted. Is it a bad practice to use `kmap()` even when the page is not on zone HIGHMEM? What is the best way if I know that the page isn't?

Comment: kmap function will check where the page is from. 
If this page is from low memory, it will return page_address(page) directly. If not, it might create a new virtual map for this page.

Answer (score 3):

page struct is just a helper which stores the metadata. it doesn't actually store any data, but the directions to locate the data in memory. That is, the address space mapping to the physical addresses etc. The actual data is still stored in the physical memory.

Comment: Yeah, that I concluded before asking this. What I really want to know is how to get a pointer (access) to it.

Answer (score 2):

> Where is the actual data represented by a page stored?

The *actual data* is in a physical page address by at least one virtual address **AND/OR** it is on disk in an *inode* and has never been mapped.  For the *inode* case, accessing the virtual address will trigger a *page fault* and that handler will read the memory into a physical page and the *faulted* code will resume.

> And how to get a pointer to it?

I believe that the `struct page` is contained in another array, like [mem_map](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c#L79). For instance the function [mem_map_next](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/internal.h#L257), is use to iterate through an array of `struct page`.  Perhaps the structure you are interested in is [`struct vm_area_struct`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm_types.h#L228)?  This is a *virtual address* tracking structure.  There maybe multiple *virtual addresses* mapping to the same *physical page*.

You need to know the context of a composing struct to know the address a `struct page` represents.  Then it is simply a base address plus the index multiplied by the page size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm still confused. If I have a function in the `mm/` that receives a `struct page*` as argument, how can I access the data? In my specific case I'm sure that the page is still in memory when the function is called, but I would like to know more specifically how (using function calls or wathever) to access the data in each scenario you described knowing I only have the `struct page*` representing the actual page.

Comment: To access the data, you need a virtual address.  See [Section 3.7 of Understanding Page table management](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html); which applies to the **x86**.  There is a straight *phys to virt* mapping so you should be able to get a virtual address that points to the `struct page` underlying memory.  When you say *an address*, you need to specify *virtual* or *physical* when talking about **mm** code.